# Change number of posts to display

Tags: wordpress, posts

How do I tell Wordpress to change the number of posts to display depending on the type of page being shown? For example, all Search results will show 10 posts at a time while Archives will show 20 posts at a time, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have to do is to deal with the query_post() function.

See this codex page : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

You will then have to modify your archive.php and search.php files (depending on your theme) to call this function right before the loop.

All is described in a pretty simple example [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage)

Hope this will help ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should be moved to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ 
There is 1 global setting (settings->reading)

If you want to change individual settings you will have to adjust your theme.
put `query_posts('post_per_page=XX')` before [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) also look at: [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: But doesn't this run a *second* SQL query?  Is it possible to modify the original SQL query before it runs?

Comment: Yes, this is not the correct way to do this (not anymore) see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/10911

Answer (score 2):

No need to deal with custom queries and changing page templates. Try [WordPress › Custom Post Limits « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-limits/)

**Update 3/06/2015; Plugin works fine under WP 4.1**

Comment: 'This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years.' && 'Compatible up to: 3.3.2'

Why dealing with writing your own customized and small code when there's a bloated, soon-to-be no-longer-maintained plugin for that?

Comment: @volker: Why waste time writing an irrelevant comment on a nearly three year-old answer when you could be doing something (really anything) else?

Comment: How do you think I've come here? A well-known search engine. The good thing about StackOverflow is, that through commenting, answering and voting thing's are kept up-to-date. That's the reason for 'wasting' my time with that.

Comment: "...that through commenting, answering and voting thing's are kept up-to-date." Exactly. See my edit. And thanks for the downvotes :)