# Adding number of posts to custom post archive page.

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and the Roots Template.
I have created an archive page to show member profiles. - its just index.php saved out as archive-members.php so it gets the member posts, but I don't know how to change the number it displays. I want it to display all. 
its not using any custom post type query, its just an archive of this post-type slug

Here is my page code.

```
    <div class="purple row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'roots'); ?>
  </div>
  <?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="row pagecontent">
  <div class="container">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <?php get_template_part('templates/members', get_post_format()); ?>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <nav class="post-nav">
    <ul class="pager">
      <li class="next"><?php next_posts_link(__('Next Page &rarr;', 'roots')); ?></li>
      <li class="previous"><?php previous_posts_link(__('&larr; Previous Page', 'roots')); ?></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
    </div>
  </div>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Try the following code: http://pastebin.com/fytBCzum

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, - unfortunately that just returns a blank page of no posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question has already been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225778/change-number-of-posts-to-display)

The answer in that thread links to the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) on using the query_post() function.

That, or as someone else in the thread states, you can try changing the settings in the admin interface (settings -> reading). There, you'll see a box that allows you to change how many posts are displayed on a page.

Comment: i have already viewed this post and don't want to change the settinfs in reading as that will affect the standard blog posts page too. - this is a custom post type and i'm just using index.php as an archive template so it doesn't have wp_query or query_posts in the code - thats why im unsure as to how I would add the post count. Thanks

Comment: From my personal experience, the only way to achieve this would be by using query_post(). The rest of the page would then be changed to something like that in your content.php file.